# Batch: Read a txt file and output the last 10 lines a comma separated line

Tags: batch-file

I have a simple batch file  which reads the last 10 lines from a batch file and then outputs those 10 lines a new txt file but I need it to output as a comma separated line/string.

```
@echo off
for /f %%i in ('find /v /c "" ^< C:\Path To File\File.txt') do set /a lines=%%i
set /a startLine=%lines% - 10
more /e +%startLine% C:\Path To File\File.txt > Output.txt
```

Also,  is it possible reverse the line order in the new txt file so the last line is at the beginning of the comma separated line

Example of what I'm after:

> line1
>   line2
>   line3
>   line4

outputted as

```
line4, line3, line2, line1
```

Comment: Just use another FOR /F to parse the output of the `MORE` command instead of redirecting it to a file.  Then instead of creating a variable and appending to it, just add the new line to the beginning.

Comment: `for /F "delims=" %%a in ('more /e +%startLine% "C:\Path To File\File.txt"') do set "output=%%a, !output!"` and `echo %output:~0,-2%`. Don't forget to `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` at beginning...

Comment: Just a tidbit of information. If your file is over 65,534 lines this code will fail as the MORE command will pause at that point.

Comment: Thanks for the responses Squash and Aacini, I've gone with the powershell one below just because of the lines limit and future proofing but yours would have worked just as well

Answer (score 1):

This small powershell script wil do:

```
$Lines = Get-Content .\Lines.txt|select -last 10
($Lines[($Lines.Length-1)..0]) -join(', ')|Set-Content Lines-new.txt
```

To be on topic wrapped in a batch:

```
@echo off
Powershell -command "($Lines=GC .\Lines.txt|select -last 10);(($Lines[($Lines.Length-1)..0]) -join(' ')|Set-Content Lines-New.txt)"
```

Comment: I have never looked into Powershell before but this works great, thanks